# Как мне преобразовать уголы рыскания (yaw), тангажа (pitch) и крена (roll) в матричные преобразования в Irrlicht?

Tags: c++, opengl

Какой правильный метод для получения матрицы преобразования в Irrlicht от рыскания, тангажа и крена значений ?
Например, есть такие методы, как `D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll ( matrix , yaw, pitch , roll ) ;`
И как применить его к камере? Что-то вроде `matrix.transform ( )` ?
Какие аналоги есть в Irrlicht ?

Также, будут интересны любые решения: на ogre, directx, чистом opengl, delta3d.

Answer (score 1):

В сущности, это просто последовательные повороты системы координат вокруг всех осей (по одному на каждую), накладывающиеся друг на друга (т. е. повороты производятся вокруг осей, уже повёрнутых предыдущими поворотами):

- Сначала вокруг вертикальной оси (на **yaw**)
- Затем вокруг горизонтальной оси, лежащей в плоскости камеры (на **pitch**)
- Затем вокруг оси направления камеры (на **roll**)

В Irrlicht есть для матриц (`irr::core::CMatrix4`) [метод `setRotationRadians`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1core_1_1_c_matrix4.html#a05aac7bd2e7651369fc813a51258afbe), скорее всего, он принимает напрямую вектор из этих трёх углов в радианах, а для камеры есть [просто `setRotation`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1scene_1_1_i_camera_scene_node.html#af95d5f50c192f212e11f3f050e92a470).

---

*Документация слабо раскрывает математический смысл аргументов, но такой набор углов это весьма распространённый способ задавать поворот. Составители, видимо, сочли этот момент очевидным. Попробуйте.*